# Access Root Block Volume ID of EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating an EC2 instance:

```
module "aws_ec2_instance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  
  count = var.instance_count

  ...
}
```

and I want to tag the root_block_device of the EC2 instance:

```
resource "null_resource" "tag_root_device" {
   provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "aws ec2 create-tags --resource ${module.aws_ec2_instance[*].root_block_device.0.volume_id} -- tags 'Key=\"instance_id\", Value=${module.aws_ec2_instance[*].id'"
   }
}
```

I am modifying the example found here: [root_block_device](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#volume_id) where it gives the example:

```
aws_instance.web.root_block_device.0.volume_id
```

However, I get the following error for the `volume` reference:

`Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "volume_id" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?`

and I get the error for the `id` reference:

`Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.`

Because there can be multiple instances of EC2, I am using the splat indicator but for some reason, I cannot retrieve the values.

Thoughts on how I would retrieve the volume_id of the root block device?

Comment: You don't need the null resource, the module you're using supports what you're trying to do. You can use the [volume_tags](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance#input_volume_tags) option to apply to all volumes but if you need to root only can use this https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance#input_root_block_device

Comment: With root_block_device, as a tag, I want "instance_id" equal to the EC2 id but could not get some type of self.id to work. I looked at https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23966 and if you scroll to the bottom, the end result is you cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to first create an output value for the EC2 TF module (internal TF module based on Terraform EC2 TF modile):

```
output "root_volume_id" {
  description = "Volume ID of the EC2-Instance root block device"
  value.      = aws_instance.main[*].root_block_device.0.volume_id
}
```

Within the TF module file that creates the EC2 instance, I need to alter my `null_resource` entry:

```
resource "null_resource" "tag_root_device" {
   count = var.instance_count

   provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "aws ec2 create-tags --resource ${module.aws_ec2_instance.root_volume_id[count.index]} -- tags 'Key=\"instance_id\", Value=${module.aws_ec2_instance.id[count.index]'"
   }
}
```